# Callback function in a $.post request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, post

If you have a callback such as:

```
function(data) {
  process(data);
 }
```

what exactly is `data`? How would you specify what `data` is if the url that the POST request is sent to redirects to your controller (let's say we're using Ruby on Rails.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is the response from the server.

Depending on the `type` of the jQuery AJAX request, it will be either a string, a parsed JSON object, or an XML DOM tree.

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: ok but where from the server (where in the application) is `data` coming from?

Comment: The part of the server that sends a response to the client.  Consult the documentation for your framework.

Answer (score 0):

data is the response that you send from the server. The type of the data depends on the dataType which you set while making AJAX request.